# Android updating two widgets with a service and AsyncTask updates only the latest widget

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Currently I have a widget that downloads and display weather data. This works fine when I place the widget on the home screen, selects the location where to show the weather etc. But when I have two active widgets, and onUpdate is called, only the latest one to be added gets updated.

WeatherWidget:

```
public class WeatherWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) { 

    //Creating and adding pending intents to each widget, then calling
    //updateWeather();

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }     

    private void updateWeather(Context context,
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds, int appWidgetId) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, WeatherService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("widgetId", appWidgetId);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

WeatherService:

```
public class WeatherService extends Service {

    private int widgetId;
    private String choice;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        widgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt("widgetId");
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("WeatherPrefs",
                MODE_PRIVATE);

        //"choice" is a string that contains which location to get weather data from
        choice = settings.getString(String.valueOf(widgetId) + "s", "def");

        initialize(choice);
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    public void initialize(String choice) {

        switch (choice) {
        case "Choice1":
            try {
                URL url = new URL(
                        "http://www.myurl1");
                AsyncTask task = new WeatherRetriever().execute(url);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            break;

        case "Choice2":
            try {
                URL url = new URL(
                        "http://www.myurl2");
                AsyncTask task = new WeatherRetriever().execute(url);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        case "Choice3":
            try {
                URL url = new URL(
                        "http://www.myurl3");
                AsyncTask task = new WeatherRetriever().execute(url);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        case "Choice4":
            try {
                URL url = new URL(
                        "http://www.myurl4");
                AsyncTask task = new WeatherRetriever().execute(url);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        case "Choice5":
            try {
                URL url = new URL(
                        "http://www.myurl5");
                AsyncTask task = new WeatherRetriever().execute(url);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The AsyncTask WeatherRetriever downloads the weather data from the given URL, and onPostExecute calls this method:

```
    private void updateWidget() {
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager
                .getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        //Collects the data from the result of WeahterRetriever here, code removed

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext()
                .getPackageName(), R.layout.mywidget);

        //Set up the result for the remove view here, code removed

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);

    }
```

The problem here is that when I have two widgets active at the same time, they both start the service at almost the same time. Before the AsyncTask is able to complete for the first widget, the second widget has called startService, and change the value of widgetId.. How can I prevent this?

Marcus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try storing your widget ids in an array, and removing them in you service with a call from onDestroy in your widget?